# Can I make multiple generate statement in one for loop?

Tags: verilog

```
module test(
    input [15:0] in,
    output [15:0] out);
    
    reg [1:0] Xai_out [7:0];
    reg [1:0] c_accum_in [7:0];
    
    integer i;
    
    initial begin
        i = 10'd0;
    end
    
    always @(*) begin
        c_accum_in[0] = in[1:0];
        c_accum_in[1] = in[3:2];
        c_accum_in[2] = in[5:4];
        c_accum_in[3] = in[7:6];
        c_accum_in[4] = in[9:8];
        c_accum_in[5] = in[11:10];
        c_accum_in[6] = in[13:12];
        c_accum_in[7] = in[15:14];
    end

    genvar c;
    generate
        for(c = 6;c < 8; c= c + 1) begin:b0
            always @(*)
                 Xai_out[i] = c_accum_in[c];
            i = i + 1;
        end

        for(c = 4;c < 6; c= c + 1) begin:b1
            always @(*)
                 Xai_out[i] = c_accum_in[c];
             i = i + 1;
        end

        for(c = 2;c < 4; c= c + 1) begin:b2
            always @(*)
                 Xai_out[i] = c_accum_in[c];
             i = i + 1;
        end

        for(c = 0;c < 2; c= c + 1) begin:b3
            always @(*)
                 Xai_out[i] = c_accum_in[c];
             i = i + 1;
        end
    endgenerate

endmodule
```

I made a rotation code that change their place.

There are error every near text `i = i + 1` (*expecting "." or "("*).

I'm not sure what's the syntax error with this part.

Is it impossible to use `i` in the generate statement?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code:

1. `i` is a dynamic variable and therefore it cannot be used in the 'generate' block which can only operate constants.
2. even if it was a constant, the expression like `i = i + 1` are not allowed in generate blocks.

To keep the *generatness* of the code you need to get rid of both. In your case you can do something like the following:

```
          genvar c;
            generate
                for(c = 6;c < 8; c= c + 1) begin:b0
                    always @(*)
                      Xai_out[c-6] = c_accum_in[c-6];
                 end

                for(c = 4;c < 6; c= c + 1) begin:b1
                    always @(*)
                      Xai_out[3+c-4] = c_accum_in[3+c-4];
                end

                for(c = 2;c < 4; c= c + 1) begin:b2
                    always @(*)
                      Xai_out[5 + c - 2] = c_accum_in[5 + c - 2];
                end

                for(c = 0;c < 2; c= c + 1) begin:b3
                    always @(*)
                      Xai_out[7 + c] = c_accum_in[7 + c];
                end
            endgenerate
```

It moves expressions into bit subscripts, but required careful calculation on your part. I hope, I was correct in this case :-)

Answer (score 0):

No generate blocks needed.
This compiles without warnings in 3 simulators.

```
module test(
    input [15:0] in,
    output [15:0] out);
    
    reg [1:0] Xai_out [7:0];
    reg [1:0] c_accum_in [7:0];
    
    integer i;
    
    initial begin
        i = 10'd0;
    end
    
    always @(*) begin
        c_accum_in[0] = in[1:0];
        c_accum_in[1] = in[3:2];
        c_accum_in[2] = in[5:4];
        c_accum_in[3] = in[7:6];
        c_accum_in[4] = in[9:8];
        c_accum_in[5] = in[11:10];
        c_accum_in[6] = in[13:12];
        c_accum_in[7] = in[15:14];
    end

     always @(*) begin :always_block
       //
       int i,j,k,l;
       //
       for(int c = 6;c < 8; c= c + 1) begin:b0
         Xai_out[i] = c_accum_in[c];
         i = i + 1;
       end
         
       for(int c = 4;c < 6; c= c + 1) begin:b1
         Xai_out[j] = c_accum_in[c];
         j = j + 1;
        end
       
       for(int c = 2;c < 4; c= c + 1) begin:b2
          Xai_out[k] = c_accum_in[c];
           k = k + 1;
        end
         
       for(int c = 0;c < 2; c= c + 1) begin:b3
          Xai_out[l] = c_accum_in[c];
          l = l + 1;
        end
      // 
      end:always_block

endmodule
```